# Why Laravel Eloquent HavingRaw returns a null value?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The following query I am trying to write in Laravel Eloquent which returns null value. I have no idea what I am doing wrong in the following query.

**SQL Query::**

```
SELECT orders.user_id FROM orders JOIN order_item ON order_item.order_id = orders.id GROUP BY orders.user_id HAVING COUNT(orders.user_id)>700
```

**Eloquent Query Builder::**

```
             return DB::table('orders')                
                    ->join('order_item', 'order_item.id', '=', 'orders.id')
                        ->groupBy('orders.user_id')
                        ->select('orders.user_id')
                            ->having(DB::raw('COUNT(orders.user_id) > 700'))
                                ->get()
```

Comment: Know that there's also `havingRaw`, so try with `havingRaw('COUNT(orders.user_id) > 700')` too.

Comment: `order_item.order_id` is different in raw query `order_item.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order_item.id to order_item.order_id and use havingRaw instead of DB::raw in having clause. See the following right query.

```
return DB::table('orders')                
                    ->join('order_item', 'order_item.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
                        ->groupBy('orders.user_id')
                        ->select('orders.user_id')
                            ->havingRaw('COUNT(orders.user_id) > 700')
                                ->get()
```